# Type define an Enum in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a TypeScript Enum that lives within a different namespace to the file I am trying to use it in. The namespace for now unavoidable reasons is long and cumbersome to write

The project is not using modules and does not have a module loader so no imports or exports. My hands are tied here unfortunately. We bundle files manually.

```js
enum Movement {
    run,
    walk
}
```

```js
function Move(movement: App.System.User.Area.Movement) { 
    if (movement === App.System.User.Area.Movement.run) { //... }
    //....
}
```

I am able to use it seems the `type` keyword to (and I am not sure this is the TypeScript word for it) type def that long namespace away.

```js
type MovementType = App.System.User.Area.Movement;
function Move(movement: MovementType) { 
    if (movement === App.System.User.Area.Movement.run) { //... }
    //....
}
```

But I cannot use that type def'd type in the equals comparison in my function above because "MovementType only refers to a type but is being used as a value here" when I try to do:

```js
type MovementType = App.System.User.Area.Movement;
function Move(movement: MovementType) { 
    if (movement === MovementType.run) { //... }
    //....
}
```

Is there any way to get around this? Why can't I use it in the conditional statement while I can have it as a parameter? How can I get around my very long namespace?

---

I am currently using TypeScript 3.1

Comment: An `enum` is both a set of values and a type. The `type` keyword creates a kind of  _alias_  for the type (that you can use after the `:` for instance). But indeed I don't think you can use the type alias when you want to access the values of the enum, so the `type` keyword is not the solution IMO.

Comment: You should be able to achieve something next to what you need with `import`, IMO

Comment: try `import area = App.System.User.Area;`, then use `area.Movement` instead of `App.System.User.Area.Movement`. Does this work?

Comment: We aren't using modules, again an artifact of the projects age so no imports :(

Comment: Ha? Could you still try, because this is to use `import` as a way to alias a namespace, not to import a module, maybe your restriction doesn't apply here.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: In the case it doesn't work, you can have a look at the last section of the docs(see my link in my answer). There is a mention of "ambient namespaces", and how to use `declare` for this. I don't know how it works, nor do I have the time to experiment properly, but it might worth investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pac0 mentioned, an enum is both a set of values and a type.
If the import solution doesn't work for you, you could try aliasing both the type and value.

```
type MovementType = App.System.User.Area.Movement;
const Movement = App.System.User.Area.Movement;
function Move(movement: MovementType) { 
    if (movement === Movement.run) { //... }
    //....
}
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBJBvAUEnSIA8YB7AJwBclRJYFkAhDbXZg48vYAVzCQGFHmg3AA0ANEgCa4gFpMhAXzlJFizGQCeMZAFEuYfgF5UAOjrHeAbkzwiwKBQh7DJs5cwAzTsHhkAlraR3IiIACgA3EAAbAC4kXW5eAEoBXF93JHCopAMcjgTjYWSsIRwbOyJIiGNIogBzEIAiAAsISJqGxKtmFUwPYJDHfIlOoA) on TypeScript Playground

Comment: Without bundling, this looks like the best option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `type` keyword is indeed only creating an alias for the *type* that is defined by the `enum`, it can't work to access the *values* of the enum (hence, the explicit error messages).

You can achieve something similar to what you want by aliasing the long namespace with `import` :

```
import area = App.System.User.Area;

function Move(movement: area.Movement) { 
    if (movement === area.Movement.run) { //... }
    //....
}
```

That should at least help a bit.

More info in [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases).

[Example on TypeScript playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBGMkG8BQS9IgA8YB7AJwBclRJYFkBlATygojC1326NMuvDQ4iJAFUoEMp24z8vclRpD6qMhBDTZWvPP4RgAVw4BZEgDd2+qjm238ZA8AA0XO9wC+r25+0-8nz2wASzA+KhA1DQBeVHQAOmZWdjjxSTiUSIBubGwAM0d4CiCSYCRTCwAKMHNLYAoALiQI9Tjy2ooASiwkLyDcpCqayDqkKLGmyNahqziHYC6bLQB6JaQ49bivAKA)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Pac0, please see my comment above. I have updated the question

Comment: ok, If this doesn't work, I'll let my answer stay, as it could be useful for others having a similar problem, and with my sympathy for this not helping you in your case!

Comment: That is fine. Yes no luck but your answer might be helpful for others. I should have included the no-modules stuff from the ofset